# How to show modal popup on page index changed event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one user control having gridview in it.In my aspx page i have modal popup to show this user control.So,when i click on page index modal popup get disappears.

So,how can i avoid disappearance of modal popup on page index change in asp.net.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to display the Popup? AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: yes i have used ajaxcontroltoolkit.

Answer (score 0):

C# code:

```
public bool showModelPopup = false;

void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  showModelPopup  = true;
  //Your code
}
```

.apsx: (jQuery)

```
$(function(){
  if ("<%=showModelPopup%>" == "true") 
   $("#ModelPopUpID").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every postback will cause the Popup to disappear. If just certain postsback can handle during your popup you could put a `MyModalPopupExtender.Show()` into the code that handles that postbacks.